# JSTL error - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: jstl, web.xml

First of all, I'm a newbie to JSP :). I've been trying to use JSTL today, version 1.2. I included info in my xml and the dependency in the pom. There is also `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`  in the jsp.

The error message I get is:
    /index.jsp(3,15) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I've been rereading previous forum posts, but nothing helped so far. Actually, different posts suggest different things. So a simple tutorial would be very much appreciated :).

Thanks a TON already!
my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

</web-app>
```

my index.jsp
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    
    JSTL Functions

```
<c:out value="this is simply some text" />  

<br>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit to run the tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- Java servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Velocity templating engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

structure of the deployed app:

- test

  - index.jsp
  - META-INF
  - WEB-INF

    - classes
    - lib

      - commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
      - commons-lang-2.4.jar
      - jstl-1.2.jar
      - velocity-1.7.jar
  - web.xml
- test.war

Comment: Show us your dependencies declaration, and tell us which jar files are under WEB-INF/lib in the deployed webapp.

Comment: I am using jetty 8. The lib folder has: commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
velocity-1.7.jar

Comment: It would also help if someone could post a simple, working app using JSTL and jetty...all my tries have resulted in the error described above.

Comment: Then that's the problem. The libraries of a Java EE webapp must be in WEB-INF/lib in the deployed (exploded) war file.

Comment: I don't understand, jstl1.2. is in the lib file, as I posted, right?

Comment: commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
velocity-1.7.jar

Comment: Which lib file are you talking about? Also, servlet-api and jsp-api should not be in WEB-INF/lib. You should declare them with the provided scope in the pom since they're provided by the web container. Show us the structur of your deployed webapp.

Comment: I meant the lib folder. Which scope should I use then?

Comment: `try
    index.jsp
    META-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
    maven
    WEB-INF
    classes
    lib
    commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
    commons-lang-2.4.jar
    jsp-api-2.1.jar
    jstl-1.2.jar
    servlet-api-2.5.jar
    velocity-1.7.jar
    web.xml`

Comment: Edit your question. In the comments, it's unreadable. And make sure to show the structure of the deployed web app. Not the structure of your project sources. I told you which scope to use already: the `provided` scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a bug with jetty8 and JSTL. Using jetty7 instead solved my problem :)